# Container Failing to deploy on GKE

Tags: go, kubernetes, deployment

I have a container written in go. It deploys and runs on my DockerDesktop & on my Kubernetes cluster in DockerDesktop.

I have pushed the same container to Artefact Repository and it fails to deploy.

So I deployed it to CloudRun, and it works! Very confused.

My GKE cluster is autopilot so I assume the are no resource issues.

I expected to get a running container however i got

Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient cpu.
PodUnschedulable
Reason
Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient cpu.
Learn more
Source
gmail-sender-7944d6d4d4-tsdt9
gmail-sender-7944d6d4d4-pc9xp
gmail-sender-7944d6d4d4-kdlds
PodUnschedulable Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient memory.

My deployment file is as follows

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gmail-sender
  labels:
    app: gmail-sender
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gmail-sender
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gmail-sender
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gmail-sender
          image: europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ea-website-359514/gmail-sender/gmail-sender:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8099
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gmail-sender-cluster-ip
  labels:
    app: gmail-sender
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8099
      protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Need a lot more information in order to help. Can you run `kubectl describe po <name-of-pod>` and report back with the `Events` in the output? That'll be a good starting point.

Comment: the pod is as follows

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error it is clear that node doesnt have sufficient memory and cpu to schedule/run the workload. Check the node configuration and ensure that resources are available on the node to host the workload

```
Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient cpu. 
PodUnschedulable Reason Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient cpu. 

Learn more Source gmail-sender-7944d6d4d4-tsdt9 
gmail-sender-7944d6d4d4-pc9xp gmail-sender-7944d6d4d4-kdlds PodUnschedulable 
Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient memory.
```

Comment: Yes that does look clear, but surprises me as I only have; nginx ingress controller and Cert-Manager running together with one other container, a UI again written in GO, added to this, the cluster is built with Auto-pilot, it seems unlikely, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Name:             gmail-sender-7944d6d4d4-kdlds
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             gk3-web-cluster-default-pool-4e6aaa4a-blls/10.154.0.21
Start Time:       Tue, 01 Nov 2022 19:59:14 +0000
Labels:           app=gmail-sender
                  pod-template-hash=7944d6d4d4
Annotations:      seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
Status:           Running
IP:               10.33.129.72
IPs:
  IP:           10.33.129.72
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/gmail-sender-7944d6d4d4

Comment: Containers:
  gmail-sender-sha256-1:
    Container ID:   containerd://fe710eb715a086b53e0dd9cfeed2650a65eaae4a30f7feb4b9e2b5ba0d085098
    Image:          europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ea-website-359514/gmail-sender/gmail-sender@sha256:55f26c5c77e10a28193ee80103b8677b26c44ce04ed027a07840750a60a02c98
    Image ID:       europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ea-website-359514/gmail-sender/gmail-sender@sha256:55f26c5c77e10a28193ee80103b8677b26c44ce04ed027a07840

Comment: 6c44ce04ed027a07840750a60a02c98
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 01 Nov 2022 19:59:31 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             2Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             2Gi
    Environment:          <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-cwqv5 (ro)

Comment: Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-cwqv5:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>

Comment: I thinks I simply need to increase the cluster quotas

Comment: I think this answer is too simplistic. It doesn't even consider whether autoscaler is enabled or not.